# Executing an animation before loading a link

Tags: jquery, html

EDIT: THE CODE PROVIDED IS FULLY FUNCTIONAL RIGHT NOW

I am trying to have a specific transition but can not seem to find a proper way to do it. Please take a look at the screenshot first. I want the logo in the middle(which is a link img) (which is a crappy placeholder for now) to get bigger to cover the whole screen in black when clicked and fade into another page. My page keeps insisting on loading the new page when the link is clicked instead of making the logo bigger or compiling any other transition. I have searched but all the things on internet leads to a framework which I do not want to use. Is this possible to w/o a framework or am I sentenced to using it.

tl;dr: I want a transition to happen onclick and then load the new page

Code is provided below although it is just a few lines.
Thank you all 
(If any of you had done something similar I would prefer general pseudo-code or ideas rather than the direct answer, want to try to figure it out with some help first)
HTML for initial page:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
  <script src="homepage.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <video autoplay muted loop  id="bgvid">
       <source src="tbdb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
        <img id="logo" src="logoexample.png" height="500px" width="500px" class="centered"/>

 </body>
</html>
```

JQUERY for initial page:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#logo").click(function() {
           $(this).animate({
             height: '10000%',
             width: '10000%'
           }, 2000, function() {
              window.location = "questioninital.html";
           });
            });
             });
```

[image: screenshot from the initial page]

Comment: Try to divide your question, you won't get a good answer this way. For start add `return false` to your onclick event.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, doing it right now

Answer (score 0):

`return false` is in the wrong place. It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("img").animate({
      height:'=100%',
      width:'=100%'
     });
      return false;
    });
});
```

This will prevent the default action of clicking on the link from taking place.

Comment: it made no difference still loads the link first. Updated the code thanks for catching it tho. I have changed the order of <scripts> now it doesnt either execute link or the animation

Comment: Start using your `console` to debug your JS, much faster than asking questions on SO and waiting for an answer.

Comment: I figured it out. Updated the code to the working code should anyone need to check it out in the future